# MediaElement.js – play() doesn't work in Safari Mobile

Tags: mediaelement.js

As per title, it works fine on desktop Safari (and when faking iOS user-agents), but not on actual devices or in the iOS simulator.

Is there a restriction in place against invoking `play()` via javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that on mobile devices a click event is required to play the video, it cannot just autoplay. One way to get round this is to capture an earlier click and then instantly pause the video, you can then start it properly at the right time.